In SVG Text, what about the effect of 'lengthAdjust' on Text Selection?
eg:
Demo


h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
<svg
  width="784"
  height="1015"
  viewBox="0 0 612 792"
  style="user-select: text"
  data-page-number="2"
>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="472.229"
    y="99.89499999999998"
    textLength="5.25"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >
    2
  </text>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="154.76799999999997"
    y="134.765"
    textLength="322.71100000000007"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >
    A lot of people say to me: ”Ivaylo! You are so smart. Your newsletter
  </text>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="133.768"
    y="151.14499999999998"
    textLength="343.7105000000001"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >
    is full of insights. The books you summarize are so elegantly presented
    with
  </text>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="133.768"
    y="167.52499999999998"
    textLength="270.669"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >
    so much attention and care. Your parents must be proud!”
  </text>
</svg>



The effect of using the mouse to select text is as follows:

As you can see, there's a gap.
I have tried setting lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs", but this causes other problems.
Additional notes:
In my project, I need to underline what the user has selected, Set lengthAdjust = "spacingAndGlyphs" causes window.getSelection.getRangeAt(0).getClientRects() is not accurate. This results in an inaccurate underline range

I want to know  the effect of 'lengthAdjust' on text selection In SVG Text.
It would be great if we could solve this problem.

The handling of white space inside text content elements is not very intuitive. While the actual layout of the text removes leading/trailing whitespace, API calls to getSelection() count all the whitespace characters. It is best to remove all leading and trailing whitespace.
Also, you are better off to use SVG's own API to process text position. This way, you can be sure all position adjustments are taken into account, and the y value represents the baseline.
Select some text to see the underlining. The code does not handle selections spanning multiple <text> elements, you will have to do more work for that.


document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  const {
    startContainer: { parentElement }, // the text element
    startOffset,                       // start index
    endOffset                          // end index
  } = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  // start position
  const p1 = parentElement.getStartPositionOfChar(startOffset);
  // end position of endOffset - 1
  const p2 = parentElement.getEndPositionOfChar(endOffset - 1);
  
  // line element to emulate underlining
  const line = document.querySelector('line');
  line.setAttribute('x1', p1.x);
  line.setAttribute('y1', p1.y + 3);
  line.setAttribute('x2', p2.x);
  line.setAttribute('y2', p2.y + 3);
});
<svg
  width="784"
  height="1015"
  viewBox="0 0 612 792"
  style="user-select: text"
  data-page-number="2"
>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="472.229"
    y="99.89499999999998"
    textLength="5.25"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >2</text>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="154.76799999999997"
    y="134.765"
    textLength="322.71100000000007"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >A lot of people say to me: ”Ivaylo! You are so smart. Your newsletter</text>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="133.768"
    y="151.14499999999998"
    textLength="343.7105000000001"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >is full of insights. The books you summarize are so elegantly presented
    with</text>
  <text
    data-page-number="2"
    lengthAdjust="spacing"
    fill="black"
    x="133.768"
    y="167.52499999999998"
    textLength="270.669"
    height="10.5"
    style="font-size: 10.5px; font-family: serif"
  >so much attention and care. Your parents must be proud!”</text>
  <line stroke="red" />
</svg>



